# Trouble understanding recursive descent parsing

Tags: json, parsing, recursion

I am trying to get a better understanding a recursive descent parser - in particular https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json_parse.js .
      I am confused about the purpose of the next function:

```
    next = function (c) {

// If a c parameter is provided, verify that it matches the current character.

            if (c && c !== ch) {
                error("Expected '" + c + "' instead of '" + ch + "'");
            }

// Get the next character. When there are no more characters,
// return the empty string.

            ch = text.charAt(at);
            at += 1;
            return ch;
        },
```

Could someone please help my understanding of this? As I understand it currently (I am probably wrong) it checks to see if the argument (c) isn't the same as the next character in the string? If so, what is the point of this?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have reported only part of the next function. Here is the full body:

```
       next = function (c) {

// If a c parameter is provided, verify that it matches the current character.

            if (c && c !== ch) {
                error("Expected '" + c + "' instead of '" + ch + "'");
            }

// Get the next character. When there are no more characters,
// return the empty string.

            ch = text.charAt(at);
            at += 1;
            return ch;
        },
```

And the explanation is in the comment: first checks if the character passed as parameter (if any), is present in the string. After this, in any case, get the next character of the input string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
So does the if statement check to see if the argument (c) is present in the whole string, or just the rest of the string? I am a bit confused as 'if (c && c !== ch)' seems to indicate to me that it is checking if the current character is not equal to the next?
Thank you for your patience.

Comment: No, the first test is for checking that a character has been actually passed to the function (if you look at the rest of the code you can see that `next` can be called either as `next()` or as `next('-')` or similar).